# Powershell compare two files to find differencies and $compare.length="" when there is one row missing from either file

Tags: powershell

can anyone explain me the issue here. I am quite new with powershell, and I can't get my head around this one.
Thanks.

So I have two files and I need to compare those, to show the differencies. But the issue is, whenever there is only 1 row different (missing from either file), then I get $CompareOutput.Length = "" (uninitalized)

```
$PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.5328
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.5328
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

**File1.txt**

```
qwerty 123
asdfg 456
```

**File2.txt**

```
qwerty 123
asdfg 456
zxcvb 098
```

```
$Compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content -Path File1.txt) -DifferenceObject  (Get-Content -Path File2.txt)

$Compare

InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
zxcvb 098   =>

$Compare.Length
<<<<<---- Nothing here, and same with $Compare.Count
```

When I remove the second line from File1.txt `asdfg 456`, so that there are going to be 2 differencies between those files, then it will output 2 as intended.

```
$Compare

InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
asdfg 456   =>
zxcvb 098   =>

$Compare.Length
2
```

What is happening here ?

Regards
Raul

Comment: That is because it returns 1 difference object per deviation found. If there is only 1 object then `$Compare` would represent that single object, but if there is more than one then `$Compare` is automatically an array of those objects and inherits the `Length` and `Count` properties. If you always want those then type cast it when you define it like `[array]$Compare = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject...`

Comment: a single `pscustomobject` in powershell 5.1 outputs null when referencing the `.Count` property. this has been fixed in pwsh 7+. in other words: `([pscustomobject]@{ foo = 1 }).Count` is `$null` in 5.1 and outputs `1` in pwsh 7+